# How can I get returns in Truffle (using json-rpc)?

Tags: truffle, json-rpc, ganache

I am newbie at Truffle environment. I built a new smart contract. Now I am trying to test this in truffle environment. I digged web for solving this problem but couldn't find any solution :(

## Question

Is there any possible way to get output in my terminal with JSON-RPC(http post)?

### JSON-RPC

```sh
$ curl -s -X POST --data '{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "eth_sendTransaction",
        "params": [
            {
                "from": "0xAc582e97209b67BeF04a3d3d5121131835105df9",
                "to": "0x5614A60dF0C6FB8c6EB6e4Ba253D1CC59A2b6BF9",
                "data": "0x7fffb7bd"
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    }' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://192.168.0.100:7545
```

Above code is about call function, `HelloWorld()`.

### HelloWorld code

I made test code for asking in this community

```
function HelloWorld() public view returns (bytes4) {
    return 0x12345678;
}
```

The keccak value of `HelloWorld()` is `0x7fffb7bdf7d16635144da549e9a4eedff43ed43d64e49e18d7e365f9e5521232`.
So, the data in param, `0x7fffb7bd`, is right. And also, I can see the transaction is well done in Ganache.

### Return

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": "0x6deeae5f09593e8c27fc1fb8353d5cef1124dbc5491c206f8150f7aa7e2253f5"
}
```

I only get the block hash. Not **return value**.

### What is problem?

I expect that there is output like Remixd.
In remixd, which is one of the famous solidity web IDE, shows output.
Like below.

```
status             undefined
transaction hash   0x0341a3c3f9c904a55f5ae321e8b9a9332304b518aa2a201c92135aabff9295fb
from               0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to                 0x7EF2e0048f5bAeDe046f6BF797943daF4ED8CB47
execution cost     21435 gas
hash               0x0341a3c3f9c904a55f5ae321e8b9a9332304b518aa2a201c92135aabff9295fb
input              0x7fffb7bd
decoded input      {}
decoded output     {"0": "bytes4: 0x12345678"}
logs               []
```

As you can see, there is **decoded output** and this is what I want to see in my terminal.

How can I **get output in my terminal**?

Comment: Can you try  querying `http://127.0.0.1:7545`?

Comment: @Ismael Sorry for late reply. My truffle server is on another computer. So, I had to query 192.168.0.100:7545. And also, I can see that transaction works. But I couldn't find where is the output.. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `eth_sendTransaction`. To execute a view function use [`eth_call`](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) instead.

```
curl -X POST --data '{
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "eth_call",
        "params": [
            {
                "from": "0xAc582e97209b67BeF04a3d3d5121131835105df9",
                "to": "0x5614A60dF0C6FB8c6EB6e4Ba253D1CC59A2b6BF9",
                "data": "0x7fffb7bd"
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    }' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://192.168.0.100:7545
```

Comment: Oh my god... I found that this works. Thanks. I slightly understand how to get returns with ```eth_transaction``` (for writing blocks). I should use event :(